# How to find owner of a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model User

```
#/app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, extend: PostsExtensions
  
  def check_user
     CheckPosts.new(posts).call
  end

end
```

Given a collection of posts, I have a method that depends not only on the post but also the status of the owner of the posts, here is a simplified example

```
#app/services/check_post.rb
class CheckPosts
  def initialize(posts)
     @posts = posts
  end

  def call
     case posts.process
     ...
   end

  private
  attr_reader :posts
end

# app/models/concerns/posts_extensions.rb
module PostsExtensions

def user
  first.user
end

def process
   return 'not_ok' unless user.status_ok
   if posts.empty?
     return 'empty'
    else
      return 'not_empty'
   end
end
```

end

This does not work if the posts are empty because first.user causes an exception. I could add an argument user to process i.e. `def proces(user)` but this would also change the api for the service object. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a real CollectionProxy you can get its owner via its Association. This has the advantage of not having to even load the Posts.

```
user = posts.proxy_association.owner
```

Note: these methods are not documented. I'd wrap it in an extension and write a test to warn you if stops working.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts do
    def user
      proxy_association.owner
    end
  end
end
```

---

However, you should be passing the User into CheckPosts.

```
# You're not just checking posts, you're checking a user's posts.
class CheckUserPosts
  # No initialize, service objects have no state.

  def call(user: user, posts: user.posts)
    return 'not_ok' unless user.status_ok
    if posts.empty?
      return 'empty'
    else
      return 'not_empty'
    end
  end
end
```

Normally you'd do `status = CheckUserPosts.call(user)`. But if you only wanted to check certain posts:

```
# Check only this week's posts by the user.
status = CheckUserPosts.call(
  user: user,
  posts: user.posts.this_week
)
```

Given User and Posts are in a relationship, I'd also question whether this could be just a User method. Or an [Interactor](https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor-rails).

Comment: A number of times over the years I have come up against the problem of not being able to find the owner of an empty CollectionProxy, so it is great to hear about proxy_association.owner.  I just tossed in the bit about the arbitrary enumerable of posts, as a thought bubble of what else could be handled. I will modify the question to remove the arbitrary enumerable aspect and add context to the question.

Comment: It looks like I have sufficient points to reopen this question.  Are you satisfied there is sufficient clarity and detail?  I would like to accept your anwer, but it could probably do with an edit to match the revised question.

Comment: @Obromios Technically it's an answer, but it feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Is there a reason you're passing the Posts and not the User into CheckPosts?

Comment: I abstract my questions to make it easier for people to understand, but in this case, it looks like I should not have done so.  In reality the model is not a post but a domain specific object, and the service object make a long mathematical calculation on a collection of  posts. This  calculation does not depend in any way on the user attributes, so it makes sense for it not to pass in the user.  However, the application changed slightly so I now need to some information about the user.

Comment: Your answer allows me to do this without changing the API. Maybe this is not the best way to do it, but I think your answer will be of use to other people.  As well, it just make sense to me thaf you can find out the owner of a signal instance of a model by going post.user, why cant you do that with a collection of posts from the user by going posts.user?

Comment: The existence of the proxy_association.owner function suggest there was  a  need to do this with the rails core, so does that indicate there are legitimate uses of this feature?

Comment: @Obromios I agree it is useful, and I've used it myself, but [Rails considers `proxy_association` an implementation detail](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/6795a24c61b038c64abff834df86d2d2459b2b23). An Interactor keeps the models slim and focused. It makes the business logic clear, flexible, and independent. You've already been caught once by a change which required more information, what if the next needs something not in the association? Or if it needs to work on an Enumerable? With an Interactor refactoring is easy, look for NameOfTheInteractor.call. Try it.

Comment: Interactors do look useful, and will look further at it.  I will delete the question,  but treasure my  knowledge of the insider proxy_association.owner.  Cheers

Comment: @Obromios No need to delete the question.